# Mediation analysis with all binary variables

Tags: variance, binary-data, mediation

I am seeking to run a mediation analysis on a dataset in which the outcome variable, the mediation variable and the main input variable are all binary. Is this going to be possible? If so would anyone have any recommendations on packages to use in R?
Thank you very much for ANY advice/thoughts...